# magento 2.1.5 paypal express checkout not work

Tags: checkout, paypal-express, magento2.1.5

When i try to express checkout with pay-pal  , 
i can see the pre loader , 
then it remain at page center and don't see pay-pal page
this happen with magento 2.15 i previously used version 2.13 and it worked well

Comment: any chance tocheck errors in browser?

Answer (score 0):

It's happened here with another module, try do that:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

chmod -R 777 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
mage cache:clean &
mage cache:flush &
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:static-content:deploy ; mage setup:static-content:deploy -f;
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
chmod -R 777 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```

It will reindex, clean cache and deploy again.